# mvn install from parent POM does not create target folder on grandchild module

Tags: java, maven

The maven project has the following structure Parent POM -> Child POM -> GrandChild POM added below.

When I run `mvn clean install` from GrandChild POM target folder is generated on the same path as GrandChild POM(parent/child/target) and all jar files from Module1, Module2 and Module3 are populated under this directory.

When I run `mvn package` from Parent POM target folder is created in parent directory and all the jars are placed within this folder as above.

However if I run `mvn clean install` from Parent POM, no target folder or jars are generated  within the project. Instead all the jars are uploaded to local .m2 repository.

I need jars files to be generated within target folder inside the project(possibly within the grand child directory: parent/child/target), when I run `mvn clean install` from Parent POM. How can I achieve this?

**Parent POM:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>parentGroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>parentArtifact</artifactId>
  <version>3.3</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
    <module>ChildModule</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

**Child POM:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>childGroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>childArtifact</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <name>A Camel Spring Route</name>
  <url>http://www.myorganization.org</url>

  <modules>
    <module>GrandChildModule</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

**GrandChild POM:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>grandChildGroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>grandChildArtifact</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <parent>
    <artifactId>childArtifact</artifactId>
    <groupId>childGroup</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <relativePath>..</relativePath>
  </parent>

  <modules>
    <module>Module1</module>
    <module>Module2</module>
    <module>Module3</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your child does not have a parent, it should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>parentGroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>parentArtifact</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>childArtifact</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <name>A Camel Spring Route</name>
  <url>http://www.myorganization.org</url>

  <modules>
    <module>GrandChildModule</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

You should also let the each sub module take it's version and group from the parent, do not enter `<groupId>` and `<version>` if you have `<parent>`

Here is a full example working for me:

Parent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent-example</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <name>parent-example</name>

  <modules>
    <module>child-pom</module>
  </modules>

</project>
```

Child

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <artifactId>parent-example</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>child-pom</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <name>child-pom</name>

  <modules>
    <module>grandchild-jar</module>
  </modules>

</project>
```

Grandchild

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>child-pom</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>grandchild-jar</artifactId>

  <name>grandchild-jar</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Adding parent fixed the problem but removing version and groupId results in error: The project .. has two errors 'parent.groupId' is missing. @ line 13, column 10   'parent.version' is missing. @ line 13, column 10